# Absolute time using monotonic clock

Tags: c++, c, linux

For some 3rd party library functions, it requires that I pass it a `timespec` that uses absolute time and not relative time.

To do this I have:

```
struct timespec ts;
struct timespec now;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now) != 0)
{
    printf("Error: ");
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
tspec_add(&ts, &now, 5000);  //ts = now + 5000ms.

//I pass ts to the library function.
```

And the functions work fine.. However, if I use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` it does NOT work.

I checked for errors (NONE occur). The function success but the time it outputs is completely different and very very small. It printed 9005 for `tv.sec` but when using `CLOCK_REALTIME` it printed a huge number (I assume time since epoch).

Why is this? How can I use the monotonic clock to do the same?

Comment: `MONOTONIC` usually employs the `rdtsc` instruction on x86 architectures. The timestamp it reads is some number of "ticks" since the processor last reset; The frequency of the counter is usually either the bus frequency or the highest frequency the CPU can achieve. This nanosecond-resolution counter value is then converted into a `struct timespec` and spat out by `clock_gettime()`. All that 9005 seconds tells us is that you last rebooted about 2.5 hours ago; To convert that to absolute time you will have to add that to the time of last boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @IwillnotexistIdonotexist implied, CLOCK_MONOTONIC has no specified starting point and you cannot reliably convert monotonic time to real time.

To quote the [clock_gettime manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime), for CLOCK_MONOTONIC:

> Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some
>   unspecified starting point

The only restriction is that the MONOTONIC time must be greater than the system's uptime (required in order to be monotonically increasing).

I expect that most implementations are indeed just clock-ticks since boot but nothing guarantees this.